# Check Whether Users Enters Integer or String JAVA

Tags: java, string, integer

Takes User Input and check whether user enter String or int...Need
 Help if User inputs String ask Again to input integer

```
while(menu!=5)
        {

        System.out.println("\nWelcome To Stavan Shah's Handy Calculator");
        System.out.println("\n 1. Addition");
        System.out.println("\n 2. Subtraction");
        System.out.println("\n 3. Multiplication");
        System.out.println("\n 4. Division");
        System.out.println("\n 5. Exit");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);        
        System.out.println("\nWhat Would you Like To Do :- ");
        c = sc.nextInt();
        switch(c)

}
public static void pauseprog(){
            System.out.println("Press Enter Key To Continue...");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            sc.nextLine();
}
}
```

Comment: if users enters options other than 1-5 or string it should display appropriate message and allow user to reenter option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's code that accept only input between 1-5:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;    

void checkInput() {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[1-5]$");  // only one digit between 1-5
    Matcher m;
    boolean match = false;

    while (!match){
        System.out.print("Enter a number between 1 and 5: ");
        m = p.matcher(s.next());
        if(m.find()){
            match = true;
            int input = m.group(0);
            // switch...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
try { 
    Integer.parseInt(userInput); 

} catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: Hi, mate! This was a direction for you not a complete answer. In the try section put your success code or return true. All this should be inside a function that you call with a parameter (user input) the function will evaluate it. How does it work. You are trying to parse user input in the try section if you succeed you will get true. If there is a problem it will be catch with number format exception. This means that if the user input string or double or anything different from integer it will be catch as number format exception and you will get false;  Hope this is more clear